# equation that has infinitely complex solutions

Tags: complex-analysis

Say we have the following equation:
$$a_0+a_1e^z+a_2e^{2z}.....+a_ne^{nz}=0$$
where $a_0,a_n$ doesn't equal zero, and $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are complex. I have to prove that there are infinite solutions.
I thought about two things that seemed to me to be too easy to be right:

1. Say that $e^z=t$ then $t_0$ (a solution) equals $\ln(1/r_0)+i(\theta_0+2\pi k)$ which is infinite [assuming that the resulting equations is: $a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2\cdots=0$].
2. Since $a_0$ and $a_n$ don't equal zero, that means that we have a linear expression that equals zero and therefore it's variables are dependent, and so there are infinite solutions for the homogenous equation.

it would really be helpful if I was given a direction to follow to reach the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for every integer $k$:
$$\exp(z)\equiv\exp(z+k 2\pi i)$$
So if 
$$a_0+a_1\exp(z)=0$$
then
$$a_0+a_1\exp(z+k 2\pi i)=0$$
Hence there are infinitely many solutions in the $n=1$ case.